# Brainf*** interpreter in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust

I'm learning Rust coming from an intermediate background in Python. I've completed the first 8 chapters of [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/title-page.html) and I wanted a project that would solidify the concepts I learned, so I made a Brainf*** interpreter designed around the things I wanted to make sure I knew. This meant that I wanted it to use structs, enums, functions, collections, and the module system. Writing and debugging this program was a great learning experience and I'm hoping that with the help of the CRSE I could learn even more from it.

The program accepts some BF code as input as well as a string containing all the inputs the code will use. Each time the code takes input it uses a character from the provided input and then moves to the next one. It also supports some very light (and I mean *minimal*) error handling. This program was tested using [this test](https://github.com/rdebath/Brainfuck/blob/master/bitwidth.b) and to test the input I used a simple program* that prints the user's input.

A primary thing I would like to know is the quality of my comments. I did not comment too much but I hope a lot of the code is explained well enough with variable and method names. However, I have always had trouble knowing *when* to comment so advice on that in the context of this code would be appreciated. I would also like to know how I could make the design fit better with the idiosyncrasies of Rust. Thanks in advance, here's the code:

main.rs

```
use std::{collections::HashMap,
io::stdin};

mod interpreter;
use interpreter::Interpreter;

fn main() {
    let mut code = String::new();
    println!("Brainf code:");
    stdin().read_line(&mut code).unwrap();

    let mut input = String::new();
    println!("Inputs for the program:");
    stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

    let mut program = Interpreter {
        instructions: Vec::new(),
        pointer: 0,
        code,
        loops: HashMap::new(),
        input: input.trim().to_string(),
        tape: [0; 3000]
    };

    program.build_instructions();
    program.run();
}
```

interpreter.rs

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn throw (error: String) {
    println!("{}", error);
    std::process::exit(0);
}

pub enum Instruction {
    Increment,
    Decrement,
    MoveLeft,
    MoveRight,
    StartLoop(u32), // u32 is the index of the end of the loop
    EndLoop(u32),   // u32 is the index of the start of the loop
    Output,
    Input,
    Halt,
}

pub struct Interpreter {
    pub instructions: Vec<Instruction>,
    pub pointer: usize,
    pub code: String,
    pub loops: HashMap<u32, u32>,
    pub input: String,
    pub tape: [u8; 3000]
}

impl Interpreter {
    fn build_loop_map (&mut self) {
        /* Creates mapping of loops and their endpoints for easy jumping around the code at loops
         * endpoints and startpoints */

        let mut open_loops: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
        for (i, c) in self.code.chars().enumerate() {
            let i: u32 = i as u32;
            if c == '[' {
                open_loops.push(i)
            } else if c == ']' {
                let start = match open_loops.pop() {
                    Some(n) => n,
                    None    => {
                        throw(format!("Loop Error: Closure of nonexistent loop\nChar: ']' Pos: {}", i));
                        0
                    }
                };
                self.loops.insert(start, i);
                self.loops.insert(i, start);
            }
        }
        if open_loops.len() > 0 {
            throw(format!("Loop Error: At least one unclosed loop\nChar: '[', Pos: {}", open_loops[0]));
        }
    }

    pub fn build_instructions (&mut self) { 
        /* Converts the code string into a vector of instructions  */

        self.build_loop_map();
        for (i, c) in self.code.chars().enumerate() {
            let i: u32 = i as u32;
            if c == '+' {
                self.instructions.push(Instruction::Increment);

            } else if c == '-' {
                self.instructions.push(Instruction::Decrement);

            } else if c == '<' {
                self.instructions.push(Instruction::MoveLeft);

            } else if c == '>' {
                self.instructions.push(Instruction::MoveRight);

            } else if c == '[' {
                let end = self.loops.get(&i).unwrap();
                self.instructions.push(Instruction::StartLoop(*end));

            } else if c == ']' {
                let start = self.loops.get(&i).unwrap();
                self.instructions.push(Instruction::EndLoop(*start));

            } else if c == '.' {
                self.instructions.push(Instruction::Output);

            } else if c == ',' {
                self.instructions.push(Instruction::Input);
            }
        }
        self.instructions.push(Instruction::Halt);
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        /* Loops over the vec of instructions and executes the corresponding code */
        let tape_size: usize = self.tape.len() - 1; // Represents the last index of the tape rather than the len
        let mut input_pointer: usize = 0;
        let inputs: Vec<u8> = self.input.clone().into_bytes();
        let mut instruction_pointer: usize = 0;
        loop {
            let instruction = &self.instructions[instruction_pointer]; 
            let cell = &mut self.tape[self.pointer]; 
            match *instruction {
                Instruction::Increment => {
                    *cell = cell.overflowing_add(1).0; 
                },
                Instruction::Decrement => {
                    *cell = cell.overflowing_sub(1).0;
                },
                Instruction::MoveRight => {
                    self.pointer = self.pointer.overflowing_sub(1).0;
                    if self.pointer > tape_size {
                        self.pointer = tape_size;
                    }
                }
                Instruction::MoveLeft => {
                    self.pointer += 1;
                    if self.pointer > tape_size {
                        self.pointer = 0;
                    }
                },
                Instruction::StartLoop(n) => {
                    if *cell == 0 {
                        instruction_pointer = n as usize;
                    }   
                },
                Instruction::EndLoop(n) => {
                    if *cell != 0 {
                        instruction_pointer = n as usize;
                    }
                },
                Instruction::Output => {
                    print!("{}", *cell as char);
                },
                Instruction::Input => {
                    let c = match inputs.get(input_pointer) {
                        Some(a) => *a,
                        None    => 0
                    };
                    *cell = c;
                    input_pointer += 1;
                },
                Instruction::Halt => {
                    break;
                }
            }
        instruction_pointer += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

*The code is simply `>+[>,]<[<]>>[.>]`

Answer (score 3):

## Formatting

Your code deviates from the official Rust coding style in a few small aspects:

> ```
> use std::{collections::HashMap,
> io::stdin};
> ```

The line break should not be there:

```
use std::{collections::HashMap, io::stdin};
```

> ```
> fn throw (error: String) {
>     // --snip--
> }
> ```

Functions should not be followed by a space.

> ```
> pub struct Interpreter {
>     // --snip
>     pub tape: [u8; 3000]
> }
> ```

Put a trailing comma for consistency.

## `use`

> ```
> use std::{collections::HashMap,
> io::stdin};
> ```

In Rust, functions are conventionally accessed by bringing their parent modules into scope using `use` (see the [relevant section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html#creating-idiomatic-use-paths) of the book):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io;
```

## Error handling

> ```
> fn throw (error: String) {
>     println!("{}", error);
>     std::process::exit(0);
> }
> ```

Rust already has [`panic!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic.html) for this.

> ```
> let mut code = String::new();
> println!("Brainf code:");
> stdin().read_line(&mut code).unwrap();
> ```

Provide a friendly error message:

```
io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut code)
    .expect("Failed to read code");
```

## Interaction

> ```
> let mut code = String::new();
> println!("Brainf code:");
> stdin().read_line(&mut code).unwrap();
>
> let mut input = String::new();
> println!("Inputs for the program:");
> stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
> ```

Prefer to print interaction code on stderr by using [`eprintln!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.eprintln.html) instead of `println!`.  This allows users to conveniently redirect output to files.

This pattern can be extracted into a function:

```
use std::io;

fn ask_input(prompt: &str) -> io::Result<String> {
    eprintln!("{}", prompt);

    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)?;

    Ok(input)
}
```

This function returns a [`io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html), the result type of I/O functions, for customizable error handling.  Then the `main` function can be simplified and mutable variables are no longer necessary:

```
fn main() {
    let code = ask_input("Brainf code:").expect("Failed to read code");
    let input = ask_input("Input:").expect("Failed to read input");

    // --snip--
}
```

## Types and constants

> ```
> pub enum Instruction {
>     // --snip--
>     StartLoop(u32), // u32 is the index of the end of the loop
>     EndLoop(u32),   // u32 is the index of the start of the loop
>     // --snip--
> }
> ```

In my opinion, a dedicated type alias for positions makes the code clearer:

```
type Pos = usize;

pub enum Instruction {
    // --snip--
    StartLoop(Pos),
    EndLoop(Pos),
}
```

Similarly for cells: (I avoided [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) to reduce confusion)

```
type TapeCell = u8;
const TapeLength: usize = 3000;

pub struct Interpreter {
    // --snip--
    pub tape: [TapeCell; TapeLength],
}
```

## `Interpreter`

The fields should be private, not `pub`.

I think the code having balanced brackets is an invariant of the struct, and the `build` functions belong to the construction process.  I would define a specialized type for syntax errors:

```
use fmt::{self, Display};

// better names welcome
#[derive(Copy, Debug)]
pub enum SyntaxErrorKind {
    BadClosure,
    OpenLoop,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SyntaxError {
    pub kind: SyntaxErrorKind,
    pub pos: Pos,
}

impl Display for SyntaxError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self.kind {
            BadClosure => write!(f, "Closure of nonexistent loop at position {}", self.pos),
            OpenLoop => write!(f, "Unclosed loop at position {}", self.pos),
        }
    }
}
```

refactor `build_loop_map` and `build_instructions` to associated functions:

```
fn build_instructions(code: &str) -> Vec<Instructions> {
    // --snip--
}

fn build_loop_map(code: &str) -> Result<HashMap<Pos, Pos>, SyntaxError> {
    // --snip--
}
```

and define an associated function `new` for `Interpreter`:

```
pub fn new(code: String, input: String) -> Result<Interpreter, SyntaxError> {
    let instructions = build_instructions(&code);
    let loops = build_loop_map(&code)?;
    Ok(Interpreter {
        instructions,
        pointer: 0,
        code,
        loops,
        input,
        tape: [0; 3000],
    })
}
```

Storing loop information in both the map and instructions is redundant; keep one of them.  You also don't need to store the code.